# Get a layout set in an attr in attrs.xml and themes.xml

Tags: android, android-resources

Here's my attr:

```
<attr name="taskTimePickerLayout" format="reference" />
```

And here's how it's set in themes.xml:

```
<item name="taskTimePickerLayout" type="reference">@layout/task_time_picker_holo</item>
```

I want to inflate a layout using the layout in the attr, how do I do that? I've tried using `R.attr.taskTimePickerLayout` as the resource for the inflater, but that throws a ResourceNotFoundException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this piece of code into your Activity (or Fragment):

```
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.taskTimePickerLayout, typedValue, true);
setContentView(typedValue.resourceId);
```

Make sure you apply the theme to the Activity before executing this code.

What this code basically does is resolving the reference R.attr.taskTimePickerLayout based on the theme applied to the current Context. typedValue.resourceId is the value of the resolved reference (the layout id of @layout/task_time_picker_holo in this case).
This works also with all other references (drawables, colors etc.)

Comment: This gets me closer, but I'm getting `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0`.
The context should be fine, and the theme is definitely right.

Comment: You can take a look at my source [here](https://github.com/Gawdl3y/task-timer/tree/master/android). The part that this is for is [TaskTimePicker.java](https://github.com/Gawdl3y/task-timer/blob/master/android/src/com/gawdl3y/android/tasktimer/layout/TaskTimePicker.java).

Comment: The <item name="taskTimePickerLayout" >@layout/task_time_picker</item> (btw you don't need the type="layout" attribute) needs to be within the theme definition otherwise it's not part of the theme and hence undefined and can't be resolved.